# Calling JavaScript function from Struts tags

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have a JSP page which is getting called from Struts action and setting session variable but when I am executing  an JavaScript function is not getting called in `if` or `else` condition. The value for variable is `true` as the text is printing but function is not getting called.

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<script type="text/javascript">

function test(){
    alert('inside test');
}

function test2(){
    alert('inside 222');
}
</script>

<div id="body_content">
  <div id="content_cotainer">


<s:if test="%{ #session.testVariable}">     
                                qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
                                <script type="text/javascript"> test2()</script>
                        </s:if>
                        <s:else><script type="text/javascript"> test()</script>ddddddddddddddddd</s:else>
    </div>                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the function call at the end of the body when DOM is available.

```jsp
<script>
(function(testVariable) {
  if (testVariable)
    test2();
  else
    test();
})(<s:property value="%{#session.testVariable}"/>);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your first `<script>` block inside `<head>`.